# Using Applescript to do Terminal commands

Tags: python, macos, terminal, applescript

I'm trying to use Applescript to open up terminal and make terminal run the commands given. Here is my code:

```
tell application "Terminal"
set currentTab to do script ("cd Desktop\")
delay 6
do script ("python2.7-32 snake.py") in currentTab
end tell
```

When I go and enter it into terminal manually, it works! But when I try to do it in apple script, it gives me an error what says "Expected “,” but found identifier."

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a guess but that backslash in `("cd Desktop\")` will escape the double quote, which is probably upsetting the parser.

This is not Windows, so the path separator is forward slash `("cd Desktop/")`.

Comment: It worked! I'm a windows guy who just recently started with mac. Still trying to get the syntax down